# Do I need style file in each DPI folder?

Tags: android, android-resources

If I have only one style file in *values* folder and it contains items refer to items from *dimens* file then I don't get right result. Only if I will have *style* file in each *values* folder (MDPI, HDPI, etc) I will get right result.

That is a bit strange because for *drawable* I could have files only in one folder and resources for different DPI in other folders and it works fine.
Could someone explain how Android search style items when I use references from *dimens*?

Here is a little example.

values/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <style name="message_item_topic">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/message_id_topic</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="message_id_topic">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

values-hdpi/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="message_id_topic">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: Side note: you are probably doing something wrong if you are changing text sizes in `sp` (which already scales by device DPI to give a consistent size) by DPI.

Comment: @ianhanniballake it is just an example, lets say it is a DP and not for text size.

Comment: Probably not the best example either (as DP also scales by DPI), but I get what you're saying.

Comment: Well,if you were using px, cm, in, ... then a different dimens.xml in separate values-(l|m|h|xh|xxh)dpi would make sense.

Comment: @ArtooDetoo so it would work? I mean I will get right value for certain DPI?

Comment: Mostly. You see, things are relative. And there are too many devices around. You'll never be sure your app will fit on EVERY existing device. Some users will contact you and ask a fix for their device. So, you'll read the specs, make an emulator, add the specific drawable/values and rerelease your app. Keep in mind that TABLETS will require special drawable/values folders

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Ok, so problem was in DP/SP. Android ignores reference to `demens` if unit is DP or SP. That is a right answer but I don't know how to mark you comment as answer.

Comment: You can't mark a comment as an accepted answer. So, I made an answer out of my two comments. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were using px, cm, in, ... then a different dimens.xml in separate values-(l|m|h|xh|xxh)dpi would make sense.

Things are relative.
And there are too many devices around.
You'll never be sure your app will fit on EVERY existing device.
Some users will contact you and ask a fix for their device.
So, you'll read the specs, make an emulator, add the specific drawable/values and rerelease your app.  Keep in mind that TABLETS will require special drawable/values folders.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Providing Alternate Resources guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources):

> Android supports several configuration qualifiers and you can add multiple qualifiers to one directory name, by separating each qualifier with a dash. [Table 2](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2) lists the valid configuration qualifiers, in order of precedence—if you use multiple qualifiers for a resource directory, you must add them to the directory name in the order they are listed in the table.

The [rules for finding the best matching resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch):

1. Eliminate resource files that contradict the device configuration. (Exception: DPI)
2. Pick the (next) highest-precedence qualifier in the list
3. Do any of the resource directories include this qualifier?

   - If No, return to step 2 and look at the next qualifier. (In the example, the answer is "no" until the language qualifier is reached.)
   - If Yes, continue to step 4.
4. Eliminate resource directories that do not include this qualifier

As per the flowchart:

[image: flowchart]

Each resource is loaded according to these rules separately (i.e., a lookup for each `dimen` happens for each, independent of the other resources). Any display issues you are having are probably due to not knowing the difference between things that scale by DPI (`dp` and `sp`) and things that do not (`px`) - use `dp` and `sp` and you do not need to declare alternate resources (for anything but drawables) for different DPI devices.

Comment: The only question you posted was "Could someone explain how Android search style items when I use references from dimens?" I'd suggest rewording your question or showing specific examples of what you are seeing which you think are wrong.